# Insert function using a radio button

Tags: radio-button, sql-insert

So my problem is that I am unable to insert the data into the selected table using the radio buttons. The radio buttons are used to tell us which table we need to access and to add the data. I thought that I had it correct but it did not work. Here is what I have. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<h1 align="center">Event</h1>
<h1 align="center"><a href="stroage.html" target="new">Storage</a></h1>
<form action="set_event.php" method="post">
<p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Set Items">
</p>
<p>
<br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="storage" value="concourse_stairs_s" id="s1">
Concourse Stairs</label>
<br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="storage" value="bat_cave_s" id="s2">
Bat Cave</label>
<br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="storage" value="fireside_s" id="s3">
Fireside Storage</label>
<br>
</p>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

require ('mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the db.

$errors = array(); // Initialize an error array.

}


if (isset($_REQUEST['bat_cave_s']))
{
$q = "INSERT INTO bat_cave_s (item_name, check_in) VALUES ('test', NOW())";    
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['concourse_stairs_s']))
{
$q = "INTO concourse_stairs_s (item_name, check_in) VALUES ('test', NOW())";    
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['fireside_s']))
{
$q = "INSERT INTO fireside_s (item_name, check_in) VALUES ('test', NOW())";    
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
}
NOW())";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is checking the wrong thing.

You need to check the value of `$_REQUEST['storage']`.

```
if($_REQUEST['storage'] == 'bat_cave_s') {
```